# Conditional Expression for statement

Tags: vb.net

I do not understand the meaning of inclusive in this statement; Sum of X and Y must be between 50 and 100 inclusive. I am currently attempting to write a conditional expression for that statement however I have attempted to write two separate statements. I have written them below;

1.

```
(((X + Y) > 50) and ((X + Y) < 100))
```

2.

```
X + Y = Z

(Z > 50) and (Z < 100)
```

Comment: Inclusive means that both 50 and 100 are included in the set of valid numbers

Comment: Then the expression would be (((X + Y) >= 50) and ((X + Y) <= 100))? @pinkfloydx33

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y are integers, you could write either of:

```
If X+Y >= 50 AndAlso X+Y <= 100 Then
   ...

If X+Y > 49 AndAlso X+Y < 101 Then
   ...
```

If X and Y are floating point numbers you're best sticking to the first form

**Be careful using `And`**; it's a multipurpose operator that can work as you have here - evaluating the overall truth of `test1 AND test2` - but it can also do bitwise operations on numbers, so like `5 And 3` giving a result of `1`, and it always evaluates the left and the right before returning a result so if you write `If x IsNot Nothing And x.SomeProperty = someValue` you'll get a crash. In 99.9% of cases where you're ANDing things, you probably want to use `AndAlso` instead of `And`

You can also use a Case statement in VB to quite succinctly test your X+Y for being between 50 and 100:

```
Select X + Y
  Case 50 to 100 'always inclusive
     ...
End Select
```

The phrase "inclusive" means "including this value". The opposite is "exclusive".

A range specified as "50 to 100 inclusive" is usually `50,51,...,99,100`

A range specified as "50 to 100 exclusive" is usually `51,52,...,98,99`

A range might also be specified as "50 inclusive to 100 exclusive" (50,51,...,98,99) or similarly "50 exclusive to 100 inclusive" (51,52,...,99,100)

Comment: I am converting the statement into a pseudocode. Would I still need to use an If statement? @Caius Jard

Comment: It depends on whether your chosen pseudocode syntax has an "If" construct. You said you're trying to write a conditional expression - the IF is the conditional. Without it, it's just a boolean expression, not a conditional one. Some languages feature inline conditionals that can be used in place of an IF, but whether this is relevant only you will know. The other difficulty with understanding your request is that pseudocode isn't an official standard language, it's just some regular use of a high level language like English that looks like a set of statements